# For a partially submerged object, where is buoyancy force applied to?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics, buoyancy

Is it applied to center of mass of the entire object, or center of mass of submerged part?

Comment: so basically center of mass of submerged mass?

Answer (score 3):

Neither. The net buoyant force acts on the **[center of buoyancy](https://www.pdhpe.net/the-body-in-motion/how-do-biomechanical-principles-influence-movement/fluid-mechanics/flotation-centre-of-buoyancy/)**, which is the center of mass of the fluid the object displaced. I.e. you look at the displaced fluid and, based on its geometry and density, you calculate its center of mass. The net buoyant force acts through this point.

[image: [picture showing center of buoyancy force]]

Comment: More generally, this point can be called the center of pressure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_pressure_(fluid_mechanics)

Comment: is this the same as center of mass of submerged part

Comment: @Gabriel , it is if the submerged part has uniform mass distribution.